# How to update instance with params of another instance from a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, nomethoderror

I want to write a method that changes a WorkShift to booked:true and booked_by:current_member.member_id. However I get the error

> "undefined method `book' for #< WorkShift:0xc973ce0>"

and I don't understand why. I just want it to be a button and not a separate edit view.

**Edit:** Turns out I put the book method in the wrong place, but the same method in work_shifts.rb throws a "undefined method `to_model' for true:TrueClass" instead. I'm (obviously) unsure what is the correct way to call a custom method that updates one object with the params of another from a view.

My index view:

```
<% @work_shifts.each do |work_shift| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= work_shift.date %></td>
        <td><%= work_shift.booked_by %></td>
        <td><%= work_shift.booked %></td>
        <td><%= work_shift.start_time.strftime("%H:%M") %></td>
        <td><%= work_shift.stop_time.strftime("%H:%M") %></td>
        <td><%= button_to 'Book', work_shift.book(current_member) %></td>
        <% if current_member.admin? %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_work_shift_path(work_shift) %></td>
          <td><%= button_to "Ta bort", work_shift, :method=>:delete, :work_shift=>:destroy %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

WorkShift.rb:

```
def book(member_id)
    self.update(booked:true, booked_by: member_id)
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :work_shifts do
    member do
        get 'book'
    end
end
```

I'm new to rails and learning on the go, and I'm guessing the solution is trivial, but I just can't find any questions or documentation that helps with what I want to do.

Comment: You've defined a method in your controller, but are trying to call it on a model instance.

Comment: Thank you, that helps! I was unsure where to put that method. However if I put the method in the model I get "undefined method `to_model' for true:TrueClass". Any hints as to what causes that problem?

Comment: Not with zero context, no.

Comment: @SKR, Please update the code to include the `book` method in `model` rather than in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to modify a resource's single field, the `book` link should be a `PATCH` request and not `GET`.

Change your routes to

```
resources :work_shifts do
  member do
    patch 'book/:member_id' => 'work_shifts#book', as: 'book'
  end
end
```

This will generate the following route

```
book_work_shift PATCH  /work_shifts/:id/book/:member_id(.:format) workshifts#book
```

And update your `book` action as

```
def book
  @work_shift = WorkShift.find(params[:id])
  @work_shift.book(params[:member_id])
  # redirect to some view
end
```

And modify your model method accordingly.

```
def book(member_id)
  self.update(booked:true, booked_by: member_id)
end
```

And replace the your view from

```
<%= button_to 'Book', work_shift.book(current_member) %>
```

to a link (You can style it as a button if you want)

```
<%= link_to 'Book', book_work_shift_path(work_shift, current_member.member_id), method: :patch %>
```

Thats it!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! Your solution is probably perfect but I ran into another problem, I have a column in my members table called member_id, equivalent to username in my app, and this clashes with the route, taking the "username" instead of the automatically assigned internal id. Can I work around this do you think or must I change the column name in my app?

Comment: Getting an No route matches [GET] "/work_shifts/[work_shift.id]/book/[member id]"

Comment: Never mind, I changed my routes.rb to                                         'resources :work_shifts do
   member do
     patch 'book/' => 'work_shifts#book', as: 'book'
   end
 end
 get 'work_shifts/:id/book' => 'work_shifts#book''